# Wix-Installer-How can I get setup.exe's current directory?

Tags: installation, wix, custom-action

I'm using setup.exe and setupbld.exe (from %WixProramFolder%\bin)to make a
bootstrapper for my installer. Everything is ok except:
I want to get current directory of setup.exe but:

1. When I use property "CURRENTDIRECTORY", I will get wrong value if I run
   command line in cmd.exe: "C:>"D:\setup.exe"". "CURRENTDIRECTORY" is "C:\"
   but "D:\" is true.
2. When I use property "SOURCEDIR", setup.exe will extract setup.msi to
   "%Temp%{ProductID}\setup.msi" and "SOURCEDIR" is "%Temp%{ProductID}\" but
   expected is "D:\"

Anybody can help me? It make me headache this time :-(
Sorry about my English.

Comment: Why do you need the setup.exe directory? If you include this information, perhaps an alternative solution can be suggested.

Comment: @WimCoenen: Because my installer has an config file: setup.inf. It's put at the same folder with setup.exe. I need to read info from this file.

Comment: did you ever find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue last week with a DB backup that I needed to restore as part of the install. I didn't want to include in the installer as it is likely that it will be updated and   even when compressed is ~168Mb.

In the end I included the file into the installer so that it got installed to the application install directory and set `Compressed="no"` on the file so it is an external dependency. This is not ideal but the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Does the installer still work if you change/replace the file afterwards? Are there any checksum checks?

Comment: It's a long time since I've done WiX stuff, but IIRC no there is no checksums generated for this, it just looks for a file with the correct name in the same folder as the exe.