# Preventing Msi external file from being compressed and included into burn bootstrapper

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

Is it possible to include a Msi package into the bootstrapper but not any of it's external files?

So my msi installer has a file:

```
<Component Directory="INSTALLDIR">
    <File Id="DatabaseBackup"
          Name="Database.bak"
          Source="Database.bak"
          Compressed="no" />
  </Component>
```

which outputs:

- Installer.msi
- Database.bak

Now if I set the burn chain to include the msi package:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)" />
```

the "Database.bak" file is also compressed into the resultant exe. Is it possible to compress the msi but not the .bak file?

If not can someone answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573135/wix-installer-how-can-i-get-setup-exes-current-directory) question better than I can then I won't need to do this at all! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the [Payload](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_payload.htm) element for this purpose... in your example I would change the `MsiPackage` element to:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)" >
  <Payload Compressed="no" SourceFile="{path_to_bak_file}\Database.bak"  />
</MsiPackage>
```

The MSI then picks up the file and uses it as expected.

I haven't found a way to make this conditional or flexible.. in my case it's a config file that is not critical, but my setup now fails (first opens up a file open dialog looking for that file) if the file is missing - of course this depends on the details of the MSI I've created.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that seems reasonable, didn't think of doing it that way. Unfortunately I now don't use this approach and build the database from scripts and bcp imports rather than creating a backup manually and then including it. It is actually a better approach as I get better compression, but when I get a chance I'll verify your answer works. Thanks again! :)